# Start a Linux job that has a loop

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to figure out how I can start a job I've created which runs a loop (that's another story).

The script is;

```
while [1];do
sleep 1
/usr/bin/php /var/www/mis/sms/sms_daemon.php > /dev/null 2>&1
done
```

When I run `/etc/init.d/sms_daemon start` (job I created) - it never returns back to the command prompt unless I hit `ctrl-z` or `ctrl-c`, which stops the service...

Comment: Ummm....that's because you've set up an infinite loop.

Comment: You created a loop (infinite). So why should your process return?

Comment: why not create a script to run that and run it on background by adding '&' at the bottom.

Comment: Why the down vote? Looks pretty fit Q&A format.

Comment: +1 @ajreal - you can't downvote because the OP made a schoolboy coding error, when the question is clear, concise and provides enough information (such as this). There are enough people who ask bad questions, let's not discourage those who ask good ones with spurious downvoting...

Comment: thx, I'm thinking @Ben Are you trying to create daemon?

Comment: @BenKilah I think it might be worth you explaining the `another story` behind the loop - what you are doing is starting the same PHP script over and over at 1 second intervals, which seems like it's unlikely to be the best way to do whatever it is your trying to do. If you explain the problem you are trying to solve with this, maybe someone can suggest a complete solution...

Answer (score 1):

create a function & run that in the background

```
start_job(){
while [1];do
sleep 1
/usr/bin/php /var/www/mis/sms/sms_daemon.php > /dev/null 2>&1
done
}

start_job &
```

or

```
nohup start_job
```

Comment: It could also be another script... (I'm not sure nohup accepts a function)